# Google Analytics 4 Measurement ID is not working in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-apps-marketplace

I want to do tracking in my Google Workspace Add-on listing page in Google Workspace Marketplace(https://workspace.google.com/marketplace) by Google Analytics 4 Measurement ID G-xxx but it cannot track anything. However, this can be achieved by UA-xxx ID and the data is passed to GA.

I think this is the Google Analytics version issue and it seems I have nothing to do here but if you have any suggestions or advices, it would be really helpful.

### Procedures

1. Google Cloud Console > API & Services > Enabled APIs & services > Google Workspace Market Place SDK
2. Under App Configuration tab, set Google Analytics ID in Listing Data field
3. Put GA4 Measurement ID "G-xxx" and save.

### Expectations

Access data will be passed to GA but nothing happens.

Comment: Where in the dcoumentaiton does it state that Ga4 is supported?